# Importing functions from outside a project in scala [sbt]

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a scala sbt project of this format -

```
ProjectDirectory/
ProjectDirectory/build.sbt
ProjectDirectory/project
ProjectDirectory/src
ProjectDirectory/src/main/scala/MyMainFile.scala
ProjectDirectory/src/main/scala/MySupportingFile.scala
ProjectDirectory/target
```

Currently,to use the (utility) functions defined in `MySupportingFile.scala` inside `MyMainFile.scala`, I'm importing them and using them.

But, as our code grew we have moved to multiple projects few of which might need the functions inside `MySupportingFile.scala`.

How do I move `MySupportingFile.scala` outisde of this project and make it as `library project` and use it in all new projects that needs it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new project for `MySupportingFile.scala` in the same way this project was created. I.e.

```
SupportProject/
SupportProject/build.sbt
SupportProject/src/main/scala/MySupportingFile.scala
```

`target` subfolder will be created automatically when the project is compiled. Then build this project, publish it with `publishLocal` (depending on SBT version, it can be `publish-local`), and add dependency to this project in `ProjectDirectory/build.sbt` as usual:

```
libraryDependencies += supportProjectGroupId %% supportProjectName % supportProjectVersion
```

Comment: Excellent.`sbt publish-local` it was.